# Can I do a "reverse" LIKE operation in SQLite?

Tags: sqlite, select, android-sqlite

So I want to search for the word "*ROOT*" from my database using the words "*ROOTED*" or "*UNROOT*".

I hope I'm not misunderstood as to wanting to perform this normal like operation

```
SELECT Word FROM tblWordList WHERE Keywords LIKE '%ROOT%'
```

I want do the opposite so if I have "*OOT*" or "*ROO*" in the database, it will also get searched when I input "*ROOTED*".

I actually have the words ROO and OOT in column Keywords. But there are also other words such as SAM, MOON,RIP. Now I want to search for the Value in the column Word or lets just say the ID of the row in which the substrings of ROOTED appeared. in this case, i should get in return the id of the row of ROO and OOT.

A code for android+sqlite would be great but even the command for the operation would be a really great help.

Comment: It's not the "opposite", could you be clearer ?

Comment: Does the column contain *only* `ROO` / `OOT`?

Comment: You should investigate how the SQL operator `LIKE` works.

Comment: The column has different words in it. But i want to search for all the substring available.
Example. I have ROO, TED, ROOT,  SAM and NIM in my database. Then i made a query using the word ROOTED. Then i want this query to give me the rows that has ROO, TED and ROOT for they are all substring of ROOTED.

Comment: Provide a [mcve], and include examples that should not match.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT Word FROM tblWordList WHERE Keywords LIKE '%ROO%' OR Keywords LIKE '%OOT%'
```

You will need to come up with your own algorithm to determine what particular subsets of the search term (`ROOTED`) that you want to use.

Comment: I actually have the words ROO and OOT in column Keywords. But there are also other words such as SAM, MOON,RIP. Now I want to search for the Value in the column Word or lets just say the ID of the row in which the substrings of ROOTED appeared. in this case, i should get in return the id of the row of ROO and OOT.

Comment: @McDuran: As I wrote, you will need to come up with your own algorithm to determine what particular subsets of the search term (`ROOTED`) that you want to use. There is no SQL operator for what you are seeking.

Answer (score 1):

When you want to match the values `OOT` and `ROOTED`, the LIKE with these particular values would look like this:

```
'ROOTED' LIKE '%OOT%'
```

So if the first one is a constant value, and the second one comes from the database, just write it that way:

```
SELECT ... WHERE 'ROOTED' LIKE '%' || Keywords || '%';
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate your answer:
I tried to use this command:

SELECT ID from tblInformation WHERE 'tommen' LIKE '%' || Keywords || '%';

It returned 0 results even when I have 3 rows in Keywords where the substring 'tommen' is present (tommening, tommens, stommeny).

And what I want to achieve actually is even the rows that contains substrings of 'tommen', such as rows with 'tom' or 'men' or 'mme' will appear when I executed the query.

Comment: This is not what you asked in the quesion. Please note that the empty string is a substring, too, so your description would match all rows.

Comment: Sorry if I'm unclear. I really find it hard to explain in english. I realized that what you said about empty string is true. But still, is there a way to execute this and just filter the result where the match is only the empty string?